# Postgres does not accept select query built through php

Tags: php, postgresql, select, quotes

I've got a JS file which, thanks to ajax, makes me perform queries on my POSTGRESQL DB.

I've already performed other queries thanks to ajax and php but it is the first time I'm using POSTGRESQL.

The php code:

```
function deletepic($idpic,$nomefoto){
    global $link;
    $query1 = pg_query($link,"SELECT FROM foto WHERE idf=$idpic AND nome='$nomefoto';");

    if(!$query1){
        return;
    } else {
        unlink("img/photo/" . $nomefoto);
        unlink("img/preview_photo/" . $nomefoto);
        $query = pg_query($link,"DELETE FROM foto WHERE idf=$idpic;");
        if (!$query) {                                  //SE LA QUERY NON E ANDATA A BUON FINE
            $return = 'Errore durante eliminazione';
        } else {
            $return = 'Immagine eliminata';
        }
    }
    echo $return;
}
```

If I comment the first (`$query1`) query the other one is performed but I'm in need of executing the first one too. I've already checked that there is a correspondence between `"$nomefoto"` and the DB. As you can see I put the `''` around `$nomefoto`, but that's just my last effort. I've already tried to pass that string without quotes, with double quotes and in that way also:
`"'".$nomefoto."'"`.

Nothing seems to be working.

On the DB the `"nome"` is saved without any kind of quote.
I've performed the query directly from http://localhost/phppgadmin/ with that format:

```
SELECT * FROM foto WHERE idf=92 AND nome='4516Tulips.jpg';
```

With the single quotes (`'`) around the name. And it worked!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` command must be followed by a values list which is absent in your query:

```
select 1 
from foto 
where idf=$idpic and nome='$nomefoto'
```

BTW there is no need for two queries:

```
delete from foto
where idf=$idpic and nome='$nomefoto'
returning *
```

It will return the deleted rows if any or an empty result set otherwise.